# WebView not scaling Properly in Android

Tags: android, webview

I am facing some issue with android web View. Sometime its scale properly, but some time the data goes out of page.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you try : webView.setInitialScale(99) ?

Comment: WebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set zoom settings:

```
      WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

      // enable zoom
      webSettings.setSupportZoom( true);
      webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls( true);

      // disable zoom
      webSettings.setSupportZoom( false);
      webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls( false);
```

Try this code for check your scale.